# Adding top inserts in LaTeX

Tags: boxes, registers

I would like to add top insertions in a LaTeX document, compiled with `pdflatex`. Although I can add insertions at the bottom of the page,
it seems like I can't do the same with top insertions.

```tex
\insert\footins{Hello, World!} % Compiles and works
\insert\topins{Hello, World!} % Doesn't compile because \topins is not defined
```

The error I get `! Undefined control sequence. l.23 \insert\topins` is reasonable because `\topins` is not defined whereas `\footins` is set to `253`. Considering what I've found in the *TeX Book* I was expecting `\topins` to corresponds to register `253` and `\footins` to correspond to register `254`. I've scanned pretty much all 255 registers but none seems to host the content of the top insertions. Top aligned floats is not what I'm looking for.

*How can I add top insertions in LaTeX?*

Comment: topins is defined in plain.tex but not in LaTeX.

Answer (score 2):

The LaTeX output routine does not use `\insert` registers at all except for two special cases `\footnote` and `\enlargethispage`.

Any use cases that are handled in plain tex by using a top insert should be handled in latex using a top float, typically

```
\begin{figure}[t]
Hello world!
\end{figure}
```

You say you are not looking for top floats, but that is the mechanism LaTeX provides for this use case.

Comment: Thanks, for the quick and informed response. I will upvote but not accept the answer because floats cannot replace topins. Someone may suggest a good way to achieve this by editing the `shipout` procedure.

Comment: @HomoVafer what effect do you want?  The latex output routine does not use inserts so you would have to rewrite large parts of latex to implement a feature that is inplemented using floats.

Comment: As far as I know, top aligned floats do not behave like footnotes, which are pretty much guaranteed to stay in the same page where they where requested. The content I want to place is strongly tied to the text content and as such shouldn't float around the document like a figure would reasonably do. On the contrary (again, as far as I know), top inserts in Plain TeX behave similarly to footnotes.

Comment: @HomoVafer no a top insert will go on the current page or float to next page if it doesn't fit, and a top float will do the same.  floats have far more parameters so you may want to tweak them a bit but really  if you re-write the output routine to use inserts you will have changed so much it's hardly latex anymore and you will be incompatible with large numbers of latex packages.

Comment: @HomoVafer use `\begin{figure}[!tp]` and if you have an actual example where that does not do what you want, ask about that.

Comment: That's what I've been doing until now; the problem with this approach is that my top insertions will compete with other figures. This has many side effects, for example LaTeX will try to keep all figures in order, the true figures and the top insertions too. This is not ideal because I have nothing against the order of figures overlapping with the order of top insertions; just as I have nothing against this happening with footnotes. Another problem is that I may like true figures to be placed on top of the page; this figures should be always placed below my insertions, never above.

Comment: If everything is a figure I have no control over this. Footnotes instead are always placed below bottom aligned figures. `!` may help to keep the insertion on the same page it was requested but I think `!` shouldn't be used this way. You, @David Carlisle, suggest to work with figures and handle problematic situations. I don't like this approach because it's clearly expressing the wrong intentions; with the consequence of having to fight against the poor engine which is simply trying to serve me what I have asked for.

Comment: I suggested `!` as you wanted something like plain's topinsert which does not have parameters controling number of inserts per page, and `!` just tells that figure to ignore those parameters.  so it is more like the plain definition. It is _exactly_ expressing your intention, so I don't understand your comment "it's clearly expressing the wrong intentions;"   I think you seriously underestimate just how incompatible with standard latex packages the format would be if you re-wrote the output routine. It's not impossible, it just would not be latex.

Comment: I get your point about the output routine so I will accept the advice and avoid looking into that. Nevertheless saying that figures are expressing the right concept is like saying that `\begin{figure}[!bp]` is *exactly* like a footnote, which is not. So I'll try to go deeper into how LaTeX places floats to hack my way out of this problem. Thanks a lot for your time